# How to import a js file into view in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have below view with scripts at the end:

View:

```
(...)

// here my html items etc...

(...)

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 // here all my stuff
      function sample1()
      {
      }

      function sample2()
      {
      }

      function sample3()
      {
      }

</script>
```

so what I want is to put all the code within  into a js file and place it under /Scripts folder in mvc 4 so how to do this? In this script I refer to items in the view.

so after this change I have:

View:

```
(...)

// here my html items etc...

(...)

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js)"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Customs/MyCustomJsFile.js")">
</script>
```

Javascript file (under /Scripts folder):

MyCustomJsFile.js:

```
      function sample1()
      {
      }

      function sample2()
      {
      }

      function sample3()
      {
      }
```

in runtime I am getting an error saying synatx error in MyCustomJsFile.js in the ie debug console so I click the error and first line is shown as error:

but my js file has not any script line....

Comment: Could it be that the script is being requested correctly, but its the script itself thats in error? Could you supply the js file?

Comment: my script begins as it: <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> //my stuff </script> I can see in the console that an error is raised in first line, it says syntax error.

Comment: And what is the first line of the file?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">

 // here all my stuff

</script>` what is the stuff you wrote which gives syntax error?? Are you getting ElementByID or doing something like that??

Comment: the error is in js file in the first line. The first line is this one: <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">

Comment: why don't you add jQuery differently and not in your custom js file (MyCustomScript.js) ?? 
I think it is taking script tag twice..so don't add script tag in js file...

Comment: No added script tag in js file. One thing, you suggest to add jQuery differently and not in my custom js file... so how? I want to separate js script source from html and razor code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that should be in your *MyCustomScript.js* file is the code you had **between** the `<script>` tags, not the tags themselves **nor** the `<script>` tag to include jQuery.  jQuery should be included in your view on in your Layout and it should be included before your file.

For example, your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Tests/MyCustomScript.js")'></script>
```

Your *MyCustomScript.js* file:

```
// here all my stuff
```

jQuery should really be included on your Layout since you will likely be using it on most, if not all, of your Views.

Comment: it works! thanks! also I had to clean the internet explorer cache because it was taking previous one in cache.